# How to store parsed JSON value into a variable in Express?

Tags: javascript, json, express

I am using the body-parser to parse incoming JSON object in a POST message. I would like to store a particular value from the JSON into a variable to be sent to a database later.

Here is a snippet:

```
var http = require('http');

    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

    // Required to process the HTTP body.
    // req.body has the Object while req.rawBody has the JSON string.

    app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json

    app.post('/', function(req, res){

        var tropo = new TropoWebAPI();

        parameters = req.body['session']['parameters'];

        callerID = req.body['session']['from']['id'];
        console.log(callerID);

        if(callerID = 1234567)
        {
            \\Intentionally kept out
        }
```

However, it fails with this TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

@malix This is what the JSON object is:

```
"session": {
    "id": "89c3b5d830dd8bb8b372f802aadbdfc9",
    "accountId": "1234567",
    "applicationId": "1234567",
    "timestamp": "2016-06-23T17:09:48.685Z",
    "userType": "HUMAN",
    "initialText": null,
    "callId": "7ab0b9306af2139a1a2e6cc8b7bd7af9",
    "to": {
        "id": "408XXXYYYY",
        "name": "408XXXYYYY",
        "channel": "VOICE",
        "network": "SIP"
    },
    "from": {
        "id": "408ZZZAAAA",
        "name": "408ZZZAAAA",
        "channel": "VOICE",
        "network": "SIP"
    },  
}
```

I am trying to extract 408ZZZAAAA

Please assist.

Comment: Are you sure that `req.body['session']['from']` has property `id` ?

Can you show me `req.body.session.from` please ?

Comment: Sure its: { id: '91XXXXXXXXXX
  name: '91XXXXXXXXXX
  channel: 'VOICE',
  network: 'SIP' }

Comment: try with `req.body.session.from.name` is it work ?

Comment: Simillar: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Comment: "from" is a object in itself. Not sure if that would help.

Comment: it just means `from` is undefined, what does `req.body.session` look like?

Comment: send your request with: content-type: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
Otherwise the bodyParser kicks your object as a key in another object

Comment: Siddhart, could you please show that in an example?

Comment: @JagpreetSingh Does the question contain the complete JSON object string? It doesn't look valid as stated (if it is describing an object, it should by surrounded by braces).

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. Turns out the first POST message does give me the required result. The error only shows because my APP is configured to trigger a second POST from the source client. This second POST which triggers the same app.post(), does not have the "from" object all together. Therefore the error shows up on the second try, but I get what I need in the first post itself.

Comment: You can (and should) accept your own answer if it solved your issue